# How to adjust the color with rgb value?

Tags: html, css

I have created login form using html5 and css3.

Here is my html5 code for login form:

```
<section id="content">
        <form action="">
            <h1>Login Form</h1>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" id="username" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" />

            </div>
        </form><!-- form -->

    </section><!-- content -->
```

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q4bvL9mw/1/

I want to change the login button as black and hover state will be silver color.

May i know where is the exact place can i adjust the color properties.

Can anyone help me? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Edited]

Try this:

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4bvL9mw/10/)

#### CSS:

```
#content form input[type="submit"] {
    background: rgb(254, 231, 154);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(126, 126, 126, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(126, 126, 126, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(126, 126, 126, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(126, 126, 126, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(126, 126, 126, 1) 100%);
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -ms-border-radius: 30px;
    -o-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) inset;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) inset;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) inset;
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: bold 15px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 20px 0 35px 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    width: 120px;
}
#content form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(126, 126, 126, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(126, 126, 126, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(126, 126, 126, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(126, 126, 126, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(126, 126, 126, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be change the color properties in your css.

```
#content form input[type="submit"] { background: rgba(0,0,0,1); }
#content form input[type="submit"]:hover { background: rgba(204,204,204,1); }
```

Its works for me. See in the action [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4bvL9mw/3/)

For border and shadow effects buttons modify only last parameter rgba, the value is the Alpha Channel.

Comment: @deepika Please, see now.

Comment: can you please provide jsfiddle?.. because already i have code right.. so it will be overwrite..

Comment: @deepika waiting a moment, please.

Comment: @deepika ok, wait a moment.

Comment: @TiagoBarreto: can you see this http://jsfiddle.net/q4bvL9mw/7/... i want like this.. but in that border is not correct.

Comment: @deepika So sorry but the question is answered. You need only change the modify the border-colors. Look the site http://web.njit.edu/~kevin/rgb.txt.html with all colors that you need. I hope help you.

Comment: i got answer @TiagoBarreto. and i give you +1.

Comment: @deepika Thanks but you need be more cleared with your questions. :)